# Jsoup get html between two tags

Tags: java, html, wiki, jsoup

On a site like http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Francisco, sections like "Districts", "Understand", "Get in", etc don't actually contain the entire section in the HTML. Sections are actually just span classes in a heading. Because of this, one cannot grab certain sections of a wiki document simply by selecting the id.

However, is it possible to collect all the html between two tags? Say I wanted the "Get around" section. How would I issue a selector saying all html between

```
<h2><span class="editsection">[<a href="/wiki/en/index.php?title=San_Francisco&amp;action=edit&amp;section=15" title="Edit section: Get around">edit</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="Get_around">Get around</span></h2>
```

and

```
<h2><span class="editsection">[<a href="/wiki/en/index.php?title=San_Francisco&amp;action=edit&amp;section=22" title="Edit section: See">edit</a>][<a href="#See" title="click to add a see listing" onclick="addListing(this, '22', 'see', 'San_Francisco');">add listing</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="See">See</span></h2>
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch. That HTML is not very easy to work with.  I take it you're probably doing some scraping, so I understand that sometimes this is the lot we're dealt. You tagged this [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup), so I'll take a stab at it.  There's no selector to work with fairly unstructured HTML like this normally.  What you can do is select all next siblings of the first h2 and then remove all next siblings of the second h2. To add to the pain, we can only identify section headers by their text content so we'll need to use a `:contains` selector.  Like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Francisco").get();
//select all "next siblings" of the "Get around" h2
Elements section = doc.select("h2:contains(Get around) ~ *");
//select all "next siblings" of the "See" h2 and remove them
section.select("h2:contains(See) ~ *").remove();
//remove the second h2
section.select("h2").remove();
//section now contains the elements between "Get around" and "See"
String sectionHtml = section.html();
```

Here's some Firebug output after doing the same thing with jQuery:  The first selector returned an Elements object containing these Element 's:

`[h3, p, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, div.thumb, div.thumb, p, ul, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, div.thumb, ul, ul, div.thumb, ul, ul, p, ul, ul, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, p, p, p, h2, p, p, ul, ul, ul, h3, p, ul, h3, div.thumb, p, p, p, h3, div.thumb, p, p, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, p, h3, div.thumb, p, p, p, p, p, h2, h3, div.thumb, p, p, p, p, p, ul, h3, div.thumb, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, h3, p, h4, ul, h4, ul, h4, p, ul, h4, ul, h3, div.thumb, p, p, p, h3, p, h2, p, p, h2, p, p, p, h2, dl, p, p, p, p, h2, div.thumb, dl, p, p, p, h2, dl, h3, p, p, p, p, p, p, h3, p, ul, p, p, h2, dl, p, p, p, h2, p, p, p, p, h2, p, p, p, p, p, p, h2, p, p, p, p, h2, h3, ul, h3, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, ul, h2, p, p, ul, p, div.route_box, p, p, p, p, p, table, p, div, p, p, p, p]`

Where the first `h3` says "Navigating" and the last `p` contains a `<br>` (weird HTML, yeah). The second select and remove pared it down to this:

`[h3, p, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, div.thumb, div.thumb, p, ul, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, div.thumb, ul, ul, div.thumb, ul, ul, p, ul, ul, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, p, p, p, h2]`

Where the first `h3` is still the one saying "Navigating" and the last `h2` is the "See" one you referenced. The select("h2") and remove resulted in this:

`[h3, p, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, div.thumb, div.thumb, p, ul, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, div.thumb, ul, ul, div.thumb, ul, ul, p, ul, ul, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, h3, p, p, p, p, p, p]`

Which contains all of the elements between the "Get around" `h2` and the "See" `h2`.

Comment: section.select("h2 ~ *").remove();
Would that solution work if "See" wasn't guaranteed to be the next section and there were no other h2 elements in the "Get Around" section?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DZ98KRxb
hmm... What did I do wrong in this code? I'm not able to isolate the climate section.

Comment: The CSS standard for the :contains pseudo-selector is case-sensitive *I think*.  Try capitalizing "Climate" and "Literature": http://pastebin.com/0hyqgGbB

Comment: With that code, it didn't change anything. I still get http://pastebin.com/sUGjmuAv

Comment: Hmm. Admittedly, I haven't used Jsoup in a while. It's possible you need to assign the result of each select(), remove() back to the `section` object. We should probably use `not()` so `section` still contains the original matched Elements. Like this: 
`Elements section = doc.select("h2:contains(Get around) ~ *");`
`section = section.not("h2:contains(See) ~ *");`
`section = section.not("h2");`

Comment: It appears the initial code in the answer and the code in the comment don't work quite as well as I initially thought. The output starts at the right place, but it goes on until the end of the page.

Comment: Elements q = doc.select("h2:contains(Get around) ~ *");
    doc.select("h2:contains(See) ~ *").remove();

Printing q will result in the "get around" section to the end, while printing doc will result in html from the start to the "see" section. Removing "Elements q" will not make the selection work.

Comment: Well, I'd encourage you to experiment with reassigning the `section` variable and using `not()` as I did in my last comment. I will try to get some time to verify with jsoup later today.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of .not but I can't seem to get one specific section. Either it'll be the beginning of the html to the end of the section, or the beginning of the section to the end of the html.